# Windows desktop icon for starting PHP application

Tags: php, scripting, icons, desktop

I created a PHP application with Zend Framework that I would only ever like to run locally with an XAMPP installation.

I've never coded in anything but PHP, so I would like to know what technologies are involved in creating this functionality:

1. User double-clicks a desktop icon.
2. XAMPP starts
3. Apache and MySQL start.
4. Browser opens pointed to "localhost"

What technologies do I need to learn in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you on a Linux or Windows environment?

Comment: Writing a batch file should be enough - you'd just have to find out the commands to start the XAMPP services

Comment: @Levi Windows, but I would eventually also like to do it on my Mac, too.

Comment: @Pekka I'm not sure what writing a batch file means exactly. What language do you use? A high-level overview of that would probably answer my question.

Comment: I would write a simple console application *c# being my language of choice*

Comment: Take a look at [PHP Desktop](http://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) that embeds php web-server, IE engine & SQLite, so there is no need to set up things like xampp, apache or mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to do this  with a custom written application as @rlemon recommends, you should be able to do it with a batch file. It's the Windows version of script files.

Resources/hints to give you some ideas:

- [Microsoft Windows XP - Batch files](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true) general overview on MSDN
- [How to start and stop XAMPP server](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1173) from the XAMPP docs
- [The `start` command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) (Running `start http://localhost` in the batch file should work to open the web browser)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any program that will start you the servers, and after they are up and running then launch the browser. What I've used is [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/), this program gives you the ability to make a web site to show up in the desktop, quick launch or start menu like any other program.

You can enable/disable the back & forward button, the address bar and some other nice configs.